# R: ¿Cómo ordenar dataframes en base a un vector de índices de columnas?

Tags: r, ordenamiento

Necesito saber cómo hacer en R para para ordenar un data frame por columnas utilizando un vector que indica el número de la columna por la que quiero ordenar.
Tengo el siguiente `data.frame`:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4),b=c(1,2,3,4,4),c=c(1,1,2,1,3),d=c(4,2,3,1,2))
```

y un vector z que puede variar de tamaño y que me indica la secuencia y el índice de las columnas a ordenar, por ej, si z<-c(2,4) significa que quiero ordenar primero por la columna 2 ("b") y luego por la columna 4 ("d"). Para este caso el data frame ordenado daría como resultado:

```
a   b   c   d
3   4   1   1
1   2   1   2
4   4   3   2
2   3   2   3
1   1   1   4
```

En el caso que fuese z<-c(1,4,2) sería:

```
a   b   c   d
1   1   1   4
1   2   1   2
2   3   2   3
3   4   1   1
4   4   3   2
```

Este último caso puedo resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

> df[order(df[ ,1],df[ ,4],df[ ,2]), ]

Sin embargo como el largo del vector z puede variar , necesito una forma del estilo df[order(z), ] (que no funciona) para que ordene el dataframe según los valores que pueda traer el vector z.

Answer (score 3):

Definamos primero:

```
dford1 <- df[order(df[ ,1],df[ ,4],df[ ,2]), ]
```

Una solución es utilizando la función `arrange_` (con _) del paquete **dplyr**. Primero que todo existe la función `arrange` la cual ordena según las columnas otorgadas:

```
library(dplyr)
dford2 <- arrange(df, a, d, b)
```

Sin embargo, al igual que la primera, necesita explicito los argumentos. Pero existe `arrange_` que realiza lo mismo pero el argumento (string) son los nombres de las columnas usando el argumento `.dots`:

```
dford3 <- arrange_(df, .dots = c("a", "d", "b"))
```

Con lo anterior puedes utilizar los indices, vector `z`, para extraer los nombres que requieres:

```
z <- c(1, 4, 2)
dford4 <- arrange_(df, .dots = names(df)[z])

> dford4
  a b c d
1 1 2 1 2
2 1 1 1 4
3 2 3 2 3
4 3 4 1 1
5 4 4 3 2
```

La función quizás en un principio no es tan intuitiva por el nombre del argumento (.dots) pero es una solución ;).

Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

Si estás familiarizado con SQL, puedes utilizar el paquete [`sqldf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) para ordenar data frames:

```
library(sqldf)
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4),b=c(1,2,3,4,4),c=c(1,1,2,1,3),d=c(4,2,3,1,2))
z <- c(2,4)
sqldf(paste("select * from df order by ", paste(colnames(df)[z], collapse=','), collapse=' '))
##   a b c d
## 1 1 1 1 4
## 2 1 2 1 2
## 3 2 3 2 3
## 4 3 4 1 1
## 5 4 4 3 2
z <- c(4,1,3)
sqldf(paste("select * from df order by ", paste(colnames(df)[z], collapse=','), collapse=' '))
##   a b c d
## 1 3 4 1 1
## 2 1 2 1 2
## 3 4 4 3 2
## 4 2 3 2 3
## 5 1 1 1 4
```